# Segmentation fault (core dumped) with sieve algorithm

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++

I've been trying to implement the sieve algorithm using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> primes; //all the primes found
    int theLimit = 10E5;

    void sieve (vector <int> &primes, int theLimit); //declaring the function
    sieve (primes, theLimit);

    return 0;
}

void sieve (vector <int> &primes, int theLimit) {
    const int SIZE = theLimit + 1;
    bool oddNonPrimes[SIZE]; //the array that tells you that tells you if the number that represents the current index is a non-prime or not

    for (int i = 0; i < theLimit; ++i) //setting all the array indicies to false
        oddNonPrimes[i] = false;

    primes.push_back(2);

    for (int i = 3; i < theLimit; i += 2){ //start searching for primes,we start with the number 3 and check all odd numbers only
        if (!oddNonPrimes[i]){
             int currNum = i;
             primes.push_back(currNum);
             for (int factor = 2; currNum <= theLimit; ++factor){
                currNum *= factor;
                oddNonPrimes[currNum] = true;
                currNum = i;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried lowering the size to make sure I'm not using too much memory but it still didn't work.I've also tried searching for an answer but I haven't found any.

What could be causing the Seg fault?and why?

Comment: _"What could be causing the Seg fault?and why?"_ You should investigate about this using the debugger to step through.

Comment: bool oddNonPrimes[SIZE] is not standard C++, if you want to port your code eventually, you better get rid of that

Comment: Check your value of “currNum” inside the innermost loop, since you are effectively multiplying the inner loop variable times the outer loop variable, I am pretty sure “currNum” is going to be greater than “theLimit” at some point thus accessing outside the bounds of “oddNonPrimes”.

Comment: To reverse the usual pattern: Why the upvote? This question is surely OT, because of not showing any debugging efforts. Just throwing the code isn't enough, especially not with such poor question title.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did try to debug it,it reaches the inner loop in the sieve function but the number of iterations in the inner loop is big so it's hard to keep up with it.

Comment: @AbdElHameed Well, **(conditional) breakpoints** could become handy. Also while you're in debugging mode, you'll get a stack trace, that let's you see which particular statement of your code actually triggered that exception.

Comment: @user1074069 Thank you,it turns out that I should've checked if the current number * the factor is bigger than the limit instead of the current number only.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for the tip,I'll difinitly use next time and I'm sorry for wasting your time. :-)

Comment: @AbdElHameed You aren't wasting my time, that's OK. I actively have decided to spend my time here, to judge or answer questions. That I've been downvoting yours just was in accordance of the site policies. I'd intended to point you out for improving your question in a way it could be helpful for future researchers. Think in this way please, when posting questions here.

Answer (score 3):

First of all i would like to tell that the for loop which is been run for searching for all the primes should all the primes by seeing if(!oddNonPrimes[i]) is true or not should be done only for sqrt(theLimit) as it would lead to less complexity.
below is a sieve method that i would like you to refer to.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool *primality=new bool[10000010];
long long int *p = new long long int[1000001];
int main(){
    long long count=0;
    for(long long int i=0; i<10000010; i++)
        primality[i]=true;
    for(int i=2; i<10010; i++)
        if(primality[i])
            for(long long j=i*i; j<10000010; j+=i)
                primality[j]=false;
            for(int i=2; i<10000010; i++)
               if(primality[i]){
                   p[count]=i;
                   count++;
               }
 }
```

This has been taken just from one of my codes . i think it would help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

First,Sorry for wasting your time.

I should have used:

```
for (int factor = 2; (currNum * factor) <= theLimit; ++factor)
```

Instead of:

```
for (int factor = 2; currNum <= theLimit; ++factor)
```

Otherwise when the currNum is big and then multiplied by the factor,it might become larger than the limit and thus it tries to access an index beyond the array's size.

Comment: `<= theLimit` still looks suspicious for me. Shouldn't this be `currNum < theLimit;`?

Comment: currNum < theLimit will still cause the seg fault because at some point the (currNum * factor) will be bigger than the limit,when that happens it'll try to access the index with that number which is already beyond the size and thus will cause the error.
The reason why I'm using the <= instead of the < is because I want to check if the actual number at the end is a prime or not,it might seem stupid now since I'm using an even number (100000) but I intend to modify the code so I can find all the primes between 1 and a number inputted by the user.